# how to set battery % in android mobile using adb command?

Tags: android, batterylevel

If suppose 40% battery is available in my android device, what is the  adb command to set the battery % to 30? 
Using adb command can set battery % only to lower level / higher level also?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use following command:

`adb shell dumpsys battery set level 30`

Comment: Using adb command can set battery % only to lower level / higher level also?

Comment: Works with Android Terminal emulator, after `su -` inside x86 emulated terminal on Android 9.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following command:

`adb shell dumpsys battery set level 30`

And use this to reset the level:

`adb shell dumpsys battery reset`

Comment: Thanks I set my battery to 420% and could not figure out how to fix it until I saw your post

Comment: Love to hear that